# MVC 4 asp.net additional parameter to LoginModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, parameter-passing, models, addition, modelstate

I m a newbie for MVC 4 .net and is stuck in a problem. In LoginModel, I have added an additional parameter as Usertype:

```
 [Display(Name = "User type")]

 public int UserType { get; set; }
```

But, when I visit here, 'Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)', Usertype is always null and ModelState.IsValid returns false.

Am I missing something, please help.

Comment: how are you binding it to the view? so the view code also. What does your action method look like too?

Comment: Bind to View by statement : @model XXXXX.Models.LoginModel............ Action method only validate user from the db based on usertype selection......usertype is a enum binded dropdown control

Comment: anybody available for help?